# Unable to retrieve ENTIRE data from feed url (JSON format) in android

Tags: android, json

DATA INCLUDES TELUGU WORDS.. So could anyone help me with this?

charArray size is more than I needed..

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) blogFeedUrl.openConnection();
connection.connect();
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
char [] charArray = new char[400000];
reader.read(charArray);
String responseData = new String(charArray);
Log.v(TAG, responseData);
```

Comment: Have you tried different ways of debugging content of your response? Log.v has limited length, so maybe this is causing the confusion? Try displaying response in a textview or saving it to a file...

Comment: @KarolinaRusin I have used textView & its working.. thank you..